# Force Metadata to update in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, metadata

I don't necessarily understand Metadata and I've done some research on this issue that has proved pretty fruitless.

I have a List that used to work until I manipulated the class in our BusinessLogic (added one field, "guid", no other changes).  The aspx page has no direct link to our BusinessLogic and (apparently) goes though the Metadata to get the information it's needing.  I don't know if I"m actually wording this correctly, so I'll add the code.

```
Load()
{
    List<People> people = new List<People>();
    people = signup.GetStuff(zip, fname, lname, email) // where it's failing
}
```

The error message is:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in signup.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'DataLibrary.Manager.SignUp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So I step through the Load(). I hit F12 on my `<People>` and it's not showing the changes I made (adding `public string Guid {get;set;}`). Is there a way to force the Metadata to update?

Comment: Try removing the reference to your BLL, re-compiling, and re-adding it. This typically works for me.

Comment: There is a flag to turn on and off building the project; maybe it got turned off?  I got bit by that a few times...

Comment: Thank you @HanletEscaño, That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the reference to your BLL, re-compiling, and re-adding it. This typically works for me. –  @Hanlet Escaño

Worked perfectly!  Thank you!  If you happen to stumble across this, write an answer and I'll gladly accept it!  Much appreciated!